# ES6 + Angular Controller class, getting this is undefined in callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, ecmascript-6, webpack

Consider the following class

```
class LoginController{
    constructor(authService,$timeout,$state){
        let vm = this;
        this.loading = false;
        this._authService = authService;
        this._$timeout = $timeout;
        this._$state = $state;
        this.loading = false;
        this.statusMessage = null;
    }

    login(){
        this.loading = true;
        this.statusMessage = null;

        let loginModel = {
            UserName : this.username,
            Password : this.password,
            RememberMe : this.rememberMe
        };

        //Login User
        this._authService.login(loginModel).then(function(user){
            //Set User Login & send to Dashboard
            this._authService.setUser(user);
            this._$state.go("dashboard");

        }, function(error){
            const errorMessage = error ? error.Message : "Undefined Login Issue occurred !";
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, except for then I hit the error callback function and it gets to `this.loading = false;` which for some reason this is undefinded.

How do I keep a reference to the Class "this" in the error callback ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem already or need more help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use fat-arrows to keep the scope.

```
//Login User
this._authService.login(loginModel).then((user) => {
    //Set User Login & send to Dashboard
    this._authService.setUser(user);
    this._$state.go("dashboard");
}, (error) => {
    const errorMessage = error ? error.Message : "Undefined Login Issue occurred !";
    this.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: If fat arrows something new in ES6? I used to define this of the parent scope as self or that.

Comment: really? sorry i don't know much of ES6 but if i use `=>` i have the same instance of `this` inside the callback? it's really strange

Comment: @seahorsepip yes, I love them. They replace the self/me/vm/function(){}.bind(this) code.

Comment: @gianlucatursi It's not strange, it's an awesome feature of ES6 :) (they borrowed the idea from C#)

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek awesome! Thank you so much! this is a great idea (copied) :)

Comment: _"fat-arrows"_ won't do anything, but arrow functions might ^^ _"they borrowed the idea from C#"_ not really.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(error){
    this.loading = false;
}
```

The this inside the function is a different scope so this refers to the function instead of the parent function.

Solution,

define this as self:

```
class LoginController{
    constructor(authService,$timeout,$state){
        let vm = this;
        this.loading = false;
        this._authService = authService;
        this._$timeout = $timeout;
        this._$state = $state;
        this.loading = false;
        this.statusMessage = null;
    }

    login(){
        var self = this; //Define this as self

        this.loading = true;
        this.statusMessage = null;

        let loginModel = {
            UserName : this.username,
            Password : this.password,
            RememberMe : this.rememberMe
        };

        //Login User
        this._authService.login(loginModel).then(function(user){
            //Set User Login & send to Dashboard
            self._authService.setUser(user);
            self._$state.go("dashboard");

        }, function(error){
            const errorMessage = error ? error.Message : "Undefined Login Issue occurred !";
            self.loading = false; //Self refers to this of parent scope
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) ES6 fat-arrows solve the ugly self/me/vm variables. 2) Your code still fails inside the then.

Comment: My bad fixed the then. Too bad I can't use ES6 yet in my projects, need to support IE :'(

Comment: You can use babel-polyfill to support Promise in IE.

Comment: same, lots of mobile devices don't support the some of new ecmascript features, Nor does cordova, browserfy, etc =s

Comment: Nice, I'll look into it! Though some jQuery plugins I'm writing are still better to write in ES5 since polyfills add another few kB to teh filesize which I try to keep at minimum in projects. Maybe I'll move to ES6 in the future and compile it to ES5 ifit doesn't add too much extra file size.

Comment: @MichaelWhinfrey I'm creating Cordova apps :). Using Webpack, babel to transpile the ES6 to ES5. So, no reason to not use ES6.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek =) thanks, that's awesome info. I've only discovered these issues myself in this last week

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem of passing context to a callback function. The generic answer is to declare something like

`var self=this;` within the context from which you want to keep "this"
and then in your callback function reference it like so

`function callback () {
    self.myvariable=true;
};`

in your particular case you have already declared 
`let vm = this;`
so you could use 
`vm._authService.setUser(user);
 vm._$state.go("dashboard");`

Comment: as Niels said you can use the => arrows in ecmascript 6 to maintain scope, which is reasonable as you are using the "let" keyword which requires the same version of ecmascript.